# PHP and Ajax if ajax calls same php page, is entire page reevaluated/reloaded?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP page that displays a form.  The buttons are a buttons (not submit).  When clicked they call a function in Javascript that issues and Ajax call.  The URL that the Ajax uses is to to the same php page, passing variables.  The top of the php page checks if these variables exist and if so they do their database work, in objects, echo a message back to Ajax and call exit().
My question is, after the exit() is the rest of the php page re-evaluated/executed?  I can't seem to find an answer.  Basically, right  after I call exit(), if I use the objects to query the database to determine what to display, does this happen?
If the ajax calls the same php page, is the entire php reevaluated?

Comment: If it's the same page - why don't you just use `$_REQUEST` or something instead of ajax? In any case, this might be better suited to the programmer's site rather than Stack Overflow

Comment: Please, add code sample to better comprehension of the problem.

Comment: From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) `exit — Output a message and terminate the current script`. It's pretty clear about what the result of calling that function is.

Comment: No, the script terminates after calling `exit`.

Comment: Please add tried code with expected and actual result.

Comment: Thanks.  I would expect it to stop after exit.  I have an approval page.  Each user that needs to approve the record goes in, fills our a reason, and clicks an approve button.  Once this button is clicked the Ajax call is issued.  The php page (using an Object) writes the record to the data, and call echo ('msg'=>'The message');  exit();  I would expect to the script to stop here.  But, the form changes.  The new approval is immediately displayed.  This is the desired behavior, but not the expected behavior.  I am not at work right now so I can't get to the code.

Comment: Before the form on the page is displayed the DB is checked.  Approved rows are shown the user name and an image.  Unapproved rows show a text field and a button.  After the Ajax call, I would expect the form to still show text field and button for the newly "approved" row, but, it immediately shows the row as approved (username, image).  This leads me to believe that the entire php is being re-evaluated after ajax call.  Desired yes, expected no.  Eventually it will be moved to another php page, but it makes me question how php and Ajax interact when calling the same php page.

Comment: You say "The buttons are a buttons (not submit)". Do you explicitly set `type='button'` or are you leaving it to use the default? If you do not set it explicitly, the default is to use the `type='submit'` behavior.

Comment: I explicitly set them to button

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It depends. It should not if is designed correctly.

Long answer. Normally you use PHP scripts to serve HTML, and in your case this is what it does - it returns the HTML that displays the form and probably on submit will interpret the results. But, an PHP script (program) can do much more things. You should consider the URL only your entry point to an application, not to a PHP script. This URL can serve different parts of code depending on the type of request. For example it can detect that some part of the form is doing an AJAX request to the same entry point and divert that call to a part of the code that will respond only to the AJAX request. In PHP this kind of branching can be done using [control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php). Branching when some AJAX headers are detected or when a POST request is presented are quite common examples in PHP world.

So to respond again to your question. The entire page should not be reevaluated if you branch your code for this, and then execute only the parts of code that correspond to the AJAX request not the ones that are creating your HTML.

Example:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) {
    // treat the ajax request
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){
    // do stuff for a POST request
}
```

Comment: I understand that.  My understanding would be:  The ajax call to the php script.  The php script creates my objects, inserts/updates the database and sends the message back to Javascript, and exit() is called.  And that would be the end of it.  Unless I reload the page.  But, for some reason the form data is re-evaluated based upon the newly inserted data.

Comment: But, the answer to my question is, this should not happen.  After the exit() the script should stop, even if it is the same php page, and the new data should not be displayed  after the exit().  Even if, on normal entry into the page (after the check for the variable that would be set in Ajax) I create the database object and query the database so I can determine the data to display and how to display it.

Comment: check for errors: either you have a logical error in your PHP script that re-executes the whole page, either in your form processing or your JS, instead of doing an ajax request you do a regular request - a redirect to the same page.

Comment: Will do.  Just wanted to make sure I understood and confirmed that the processing should stop after exit().  If that is the case I can proceed to look to see why my code continues to execute.  Thanks

Comment: this is why on SO people are asking for your code -> to spot the errors. If you don't put the code than you have to discover it yourself. Our input can be limited to theoretical aspects without the code.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: put the exit at the very start and see if it stops. it should

Comment: I would put the code, but I can't get to it right now as I am not at work.  I will try the exit at top of code.  And I will post code Tuesday if I don't see the error (or if I can get into the office this weekend).